# After native building, the Tomcat Unix socket configuration does not take effect

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Slf4j
public class TomcatAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer(ServerProperties serverProperties) {
        return factory -> {
            if (serverProperties.getUseUnixSocket()) {
                    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
                if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux") || os.contains("aix")) {
                    log.info("Unix system，use Unix socket");
                    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setProperty("unixDomainSocketPath", serverProperties.getSocketFile()));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The code above, when run using java -jar, will listen to a socket at the specified file path. However, after building it using native, the code still runs normally, but it actually listens to a port instead of a Unix socket file.

sprint boot version: 3.2.1
native-maven-plugin version: 0.9.28

Use Unix socket instead of http port as normal

Comment: when it run as native image do you see "Unix system，use Unix socket" in the logs ? can you share debug logs with jar run and native run ?